# Ruby docker image can't install nodejs on raspberry pi

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to get a rails server setup on a raspberry pi by building a Docker image.

Image:

```
FROM ruby:latest

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

WORKDIR /webapp

COPY Gemfile* /webapp
RUN bundle install

COPY . /webapp/

CMD ["rails", "s", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

But I'm getting

> E: Package 'nodejs' has no installation candidate

EDIT:

I have tried adding the command from the nodejs site `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs`

Answer (score 0):

The reason the error `Package 'nodejs' has no installation candidate` was showing up regardless of how you tried to add the repo to apt-get is because `Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armel/Packages' as repository 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x stretch InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armel'`.

My solution was to move to an arm32v7/ruby base image and running the same commands. This will install the nodejs_4.8.2~dfsg-1_armhf.deb package which is compatible with the arm architecture.